# Rails 4: How to handle complex DB queries in a controller action in order to speed things up for the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a simple question about my Rails app.

I have a number of controller methods that contain some hefty database queries. These are slowing down the rendering of the relevant views. An example is:

```
 @user_json = User.all.reject{|u| !u.valid? }.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.to_s.downcase]}.map {|c, v | ["code" => c, "value" => v, "flag" => c.to_s.downcase]}.flatten.to_json
```

Which creates JSON for a Highcharts graph. I have several of these in each action. How is this best handled?

1. Push to a background job? If so, which one. I already use Sidekiq but this won't allow me to access variables created in workers.
2. Simply try to speed up the query through DB optimisation etc.

My DB isn't that big (about 4000 users).

Comment: First thing, you can speed up the computation you have there by moving them from memory to SQL. Then probably some index check. Now if you query to display data in a view, then background job doesn't your tool.

Comment: Like `User.all.reject{|u| !u.valid? }` can be wriiten like `User.where.not(valid: true)}..`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to add this on your sql

OPTION (RECOMPILE) // this will enhance the speed of your fetch